# ASP.NET MVC4 : XSP4 vs Lighthttp with Mono-FastCGI Performance

Tags: mono, raspberry-pi, fastcgi, lighttpd, xsp4

I followed this instruction to make my ASP.NET MVC4 run on my Raspberry Pi(model B): [Raspberry Pi Mono MVC Razor View Engine ASP.net XSP / FastCgi / Lighttpd Implementation](http://c-mobberley.com/wordpress/2013/06/16/raspberry-pi-mono-mvc-asp-net-xsp-fastcgi-lighttpd-implementation/)

The only difference is I compile Mono 3.4.x, XSP, and Mono-FastCGI from Git.

The performance of it running under Lighttpd/FastCGI is horrible, specially on its first run or whenever it became idle. Unlike on XSP4 where there is a slow loading time on first access but things will become a lot faster even if it became idle overnight.

I thought FastCGI is using XSP for serving ASP.NET pages, but why is the performance is slow under under Lighttpd with Mono-FastCGI but almost smooth on XSP4? Is there something I have to configure on Lighttpd and Mono-FastCGI to attain same performance as XSP4?

This is my first time using Lighttpd with ASP.NET/Mono, only Apache2 + mod_mono. Tried Nginx too on RPi but still have this performance issue, worse than what I experience than Lighttpd.